# PHP Trouble with String Comparisons

Tags: php, string, comparison, operators

I'm writing a relatively simple if statement to process the response of a web-service

The below code will output the type of data that's being returned and the value of it:

```
$response = $client->__getLastResponse();
echo $response;
echo gettype($response);
```

For a correct response, I get 'true string'
For an incorrect response, I get 'false string'

So I need an if statement to process whether it's true or false:

```
if($response == "true"){
    echo "Logged In";
} else {
    echo "Not Logged In";
}
```

Whatever response I get, I always receive "Not Logged In"

I've tried the === operator also, but to no avail.

Can someone help?

Comment: If you get `"true string"` it means the response variable contains `"true "` (with a final space), not `"true"`. Also, `var_dump($response)` is a cleaner way of displaying values and types - can you tell us what it outputs ?

Comment: string(536) " true " which indeed means there's a space.

Comment: I have already answered. Is it really `true string` you get or just `true` as a string?

Comment: The error was that the response from the webservice (not of my own design I might add) returned 536 characters to display the word true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> For a correct response, I get 'true string'
>   For an incorrect response, I get 'false string'

Provided that's you actual code, you have `echo $response . gettype( $response )` which yields "true string", right? If so, there's a space after "true". Try to trim the response:

```
<?php
$response = $client->__getLastResponse();
if( strtolower( trim( $response ) ) === 'true' ) {
   echo 'response is true.';
}
```

Apart from that, debugging is really easy using `var_dump`, as that will display quotes around the value and the total length of the string, making the additional space pop-up much easier to spot.

Comment: Your excessive whitespace usage is pretty ugly.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Aww, thanks for taking the time to share that with me. I find it to be more readable, actually.

Comment: For guy like me, its excessive. I use no space unless I have to. see code example in my answer

Comment: Interesting, I usually consider it pretty hard to read with that many spaces since things that belong together are separated... already hate it in the jquery sourcecode.

Comment: @ThiefMaster Well, what can I say? Coding styles are personal, and this happens to be mine. You could argue it's not what most developers use, but then, my IDE can reformat ;)

Comment: Thanks for your help but I'm inclined to agree with @ThiefMaster ... First thing I did after copy/pasting was take out the white-spacyness ;)

Comment: @DanielHanly Nothing to worry about, right? As long as the answer and syntax are correct, the coding style can be adapter. And cheers ;)